# PHP html_entity_decode is not displaying HTML text properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not sure what i am doing wrong and being just a starter in PHP i am not sure if my approach is correct or not.
I am using TinyMCE Editor to store some text in database and will display this text in Browser in my WordPress powered site.

This is the text actually getting stored in database

```
&lt;strong&gt;Well we should think about how to see this editor&lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Its Good in nature&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Well Matured&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Easy to use.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=\&quot;color: #ff0000;\&quot;&gt;We should use this editor every now and than&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;span style=\&quot;color: #333333;\&quot;&gt;©&lt;/span&gt;

This is going to be a heading to test it
&lt;h1 style=\&quot;text-align: right;\&quot;&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
```

Sorry for such encoded text, i am using PHP's `html_entity_decode` method to send that text back to browser to get displayed.
This is my function call

```
html_entity_decode($event->Description,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')
```

### HTML Output

```
<font color="#cc0000">'<strong>Well we should think about how to see this editor</strong>
 <ul> 
  <li>Its Good in nature</li> 
  <li>Well Matured</li> 
  <li>Easy to use.</li> 
  </ul>
  <strong>
  <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">We should use this editor every now and than</span></strong> 
  <span style=\"color: #333333;\">©</span> 
  This is going to be a heading to test it 
  <h1 style=\"text-align: right;\"></h1>'</font>
```

Everything seems to be in place except the colors information.Colors are not working in the generated HTML output

Can anyone help me to understand where i am doing wrong seems like either i am not decoding it properly or some other thing i am missing which is sending wrong HTML from my php function call

Comment: Do not store with HTML entities in the database (remove the encoding and the decoding to/from html entities) - you do not need that. Apart from that it can not said much what actually has done wrong additionally, maybe something with input slashes, but that depends on processing together with Wordpress and some more concrete code.

Comment: @hakre:for storing i am not doing any decoding,since its being added by admin so simple i am doing `esc_attr($_POST["data"])` and than i am passing this data to the SQL query, i was doing decoding since without using `html_entity_decode` my data is being sent as string and HTML tags are not being parsed by browser properly

Answer (score 2):

This is probably how the data is being encoded to be saved:

```
htmlentities( addslashes($string) );
```

Now to get the exact output back, you need to remove the slashes, with `stripslashes` function:

```
stripslashes( html_entity_decode($event->Description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') );
```

Comment: i am not sure if Wordpress or PHP is doing anything extra behind the scene since i am adding those data through Admin panel so this is what i am doing `esc_attr($_POST["data"])`, once i got the data i am passing it to SQL query to save it in database.

Comment: I am not sure about that either, but did you try the statement with stripslashes()?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight I see double quotes are escaped in HTML code. They shouldn't. Try removing backslashes. Like this:

```
  <span style="color: #ff0000">We should use this editor every now and than</span></strong> 
  <span style="color: #333333">©</span>
```

Try `html_entity_decode()` with `ENT_NOQUOTES`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,how ever i tried your suggestions seems not working same issue about escaping

Comment: @Umesh Have you tried not decoding at all, removing html_entity_decode()?

Comment: Yes, in that case nothing is being displayed correctly all HTML as a string

Comment: Got it. Does not display the html tags correctly. Well, `str_replace('\"', '"', $output)` after `html_entity_decode()` might not be the best solution, but can't figure out any other option at this moment.

Comment: Yes that solution is in my mind but since i am just a starter in PHP so looking for other options or issue with my code